# How can I put characters around a word which begins with a specific character?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

For example I have a string : 
"This is a !thing"

How can I make it like this - "This is a `!<b>thing</b>`"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not: have a look at regular expressions/REGEX with preg_replace.

Comment: You want to boldface the word that follows an exclamation point by putting `<b> ... </b>` around the word?

Comment: Post more code... this isn't suffice.

Comment: With preg_replace I can only replace the ! with the "<b>". What I need is something that will put the word after the "!" between "<b>" and "</b>" tags.

Comment: @John That's correct.

Comment: Seems like you haven't read the documentation of `preg_replace` if you don't see how to replace the word, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/!(\w+)/', '!<b>$1</b>', $string);
```

In the replacement string `$n` is replaced with whatever matched `n`th capture group in the regexp.

Comment: I think it should be `preg_replace('/!(\w+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);`

Comment: @AmalMurali His example includes the `!` in the new string.

Comment: But his comment says otherwise. But since this answer is not accepted, everything is fine! And +1 for the one-line solution!

Comment: @AmalMurali If he wrote a comment like that, he must have deleted it, because I don't see it now. All I see is "put the word after the ! between <b> and </b>", nothing about removing the !.